# C# How can I display a selectable list of objects displaying select attributes but on select returns the object

Tags: c#

I have a form that a user can fill out to add a new entry to the DB or update an existing one.  I need a view that can display the objects number and description and can be selected by a user to prepopulate the form with that objects data for updating.

I tried a data grid view and I got my objects displaying but it shows ALL objects attributes.  I only want two of them to display.  Also data grid views seem to be selectable by cell not row.

This is how I bound my data.  Is there a way to make it selectable by row and give me back the object?  Or only display some attributes?

```
var source = new BindingSource();
        List<RollingStock> rollingStockList = RollingStockDAO.GetRollingStocks();
        source.DataSource = rollingStockList;
        dgvInventoryList.DataSource = source;
```

I'm still learning to code and Im not super familiar with C# yet.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried a data grid view and I got my objects displaying but it shows
>   ALL objects attributes. I only want two of them to display. Also data
>   grid views seem to be selectable by cell not row.

those are both properties you need to specify.

to stop the other columns from being created use:

```
dgvInventoryList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

to make the entire row get selected instead of just the cell use:

```
dgvInventoryList.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

im sure they are also in the property grid somewhere.

> Is there a way ... give me back the object?

to get the object bound to the row use:

```
DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem
```

then cast it to your object:

```
MyObject rowObject = dgvInventoryList.Rows[0].DataBoundItem as MyObject;
```

to get the object when the row is clicked, you can handle the Cell.Click event:

```
private void dgvInventoryList_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject rowObject = dgvInventoryList.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as MyObject;
    }
```

there is also a HeaderCell.Click event and a few others. you should be able to find one to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped a bunch.  My dgv is populating properly.  The only note I found was to make sure the DataPropertyName for you columns is set properly to the objects attribute it should reflect.